# How to add/remove class/id on specific scroll position more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header, that i want to add a different class to when scrolled down to a certain point. This worked on the first class, but when i try to add another on a different point, it's not working. My header is fixed and i want to change it's background twice at two different scrolled points.

How do i do that?

I have a fiddle, that shows what i want? Please answer me with a working fiddle. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/madsrhn12/6q3btjs7/

```
.div1 {
width:100%;
height:500px;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: green;           
}

.div2 {
width:100%;
height:500px;
position: absolute;
top:500px;
left:0px;
background-color: red;           
}

.div3 {
width:100%;
height:1500px;
position: absolute;
top:1000px;
left:0px;
background-color: blue;           
}

.div-header {
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: blue;
}

.div-header2 {
 background-color:black;
}

.div-header3 {
background-color:yellow;
}






var num =500; 

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {        
     $('.div-header').addClass('div-header2');
} else {
    $('.div-header').removeClass('div-header2')
}

});//not working, dont know why... Hope you get the idea though.



var num =1000; 

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {        
     $('.div-header').addClass('div-header3');
} else {
    $('.div-header').removeClass('div-header3')
}

});//I cant figure this one out. How do i get two different headers, on a different positon (var            num =1000) // than the allready styled, and working (var num =500;)?
```

Comment: for a start you should understand that `scroll` event fires many times a second. Binding 2 handlers is not a good idea, put all the logic into one so you aren't searching the DOM twice for the same thing

Answer (score 0):

The key problem is that there's only one variable named `num` in your script. This line ...

```
var num = 500;
```

.. defines it, and this one...

```
var num = 1000;
```

... just assigns a different value to that variable, `var` part is just ignored. So all the functions working with `num` will use this new value; the old one is completely forgotten now.

The easiest way out is just creating another variable (like `num2`) and using it, but it's the road to nowhere. Instead, adjust both the value storage (as you store two related items, it should be a collection; array is the simplest one) and the scroll handlers - instead of using two, just make a single one with a fork within. For example:

```
var margins = [
   $('.div3').offset().top - $('.div-header').height(), 
   $('.div2').offset().top - $('.div-header').height()
];

var $window = $(window);
$window.on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var $header = $('.div-header');
  $header.removeClass('div-header2 div-header3');
  if (scrollTop >= margins[0]) {
    $header.addClass('div-header2');
  }
  else if (scrollTop >= margins[1]) {
    $header.addClass('div-header3');
  }
});
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mv59pb0z/)

As a sidenote, I'd rather have the scroll event handler debounced, so it will be fired only when user stopped scrolling.